# How to serve a static directory with nim httpbeast?

Tags: http, nim-lang

How to serve a static directory with nim httpbeast? I am working on a project and needs to be light weight so I am using httpbeast but am unable to serve the static directory. I am able to serve static files but i want to serve the whole static directory.

I tried many things but I am unable to figure it out can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does it meant "serve the whole static directory"? Pack it and send it? Show it as a directory listing where you can click each file?

[Jester](https://github.com/dom96/jester/), which can use httpbeast, serves by default a `public/` directory, but behind the scenes when the user request a file like `public/somedir/somefile.xyz`, Jester do some [sanity checks](https://github.com/dom96/jester/blob/185c61066e3522f8e2599ceeeb0cafe7ff669f8f/jester.nim#L318) (file is actually in `public`, file is a file or else serves `index.html`, permissions are OK, file cannot be served from cache) and then serves each file individually.